# Encoding a string to ascii

Tags: python, encoding, ascii

I have a long string that I want to encode to ascii. I'm doing:

```
s = s.encode('ascii', 'replace')
```

but I get:

```
'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 2646: ordinal not in range(128)
```

(I've also tried `'ignore'` but it doesn't help.)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Your string is **already encoded** with some encoding. Before encoding it to ascii, you **must decode it first**.

Python is ***implicity*** trying to decode it (That's why you get a `UnicodeDecodeError` not `UnicodeEncodeError`).

You can solve the problem by *explicity decoding your bytestring* (using the appropriate encoding) **before** trying to reencode it to ascii.

Example:

```
s = s.decode('some_encoding').encode('ascii', 'replace')
```

Use the correct encoding your string was encoded in first place, instead of `'some_encoding'`.

You have to know which encoding a string is using before you can decode it. Where did you get the string from?

Comment: Is this answer based on Python version 2 or 3?

Answer (score 2):

`encode` should be used on `unicode` objects to convert it to a `str`.
If you have a str object, you should use `decode` to convert it to a `unicode`.