# Output in my text file ceaser cipher coming out random

Tags: python, caesar-cipher

I am trying to code something that will take a .txt file and turn it into a ceaser cipher encryption or decrypt a ceaser cipher from a .txt file

This is a modified program of a ceaser cipher program I had that only translated user inputted strings

```
fileName = input('Enter the file name: ')
inputFile = open(fileName, 'r')
text = inputFile.read()

distance = int(input('Enter the distance value: '))

print('Would you like to encrypt or decrypt?')

userinput = input('---] ')
if (userinput == 'encrypt'):
    encvar = ''
    for word in text:
        ordValue = ord(word)
        cipherValue = ordValue + distance
        if cipherValue > ord('z'):
            cipherValue = ord('a') + distance - (ord('z') - ordValue + 
        encvar += chr(cipherValue)
    print(encvar)
if (userinput == 'decrypt'):
    decvar = ''
    for word in text:
        ordValue = ord(word)
        cipherValue = ordValue - distance
        if cipherValue < ord('a'):
            cipherValue = ord('z') - (distance - (ord('a') - ordValue - 
        decvar += chr(cipherValue)
    print(decvar)
```

I get something like this for the encryption

```
JgnnqVjku"kuCp"gpetarvgf"oguucigVjku"kuCFgoq"hkngHqtRtqlgev"vjtgg
```

and then pasting that same encryption into the file to decrypt I get this output

```
cjjmÎÎfgq¸gqÎÎl¸clapwnrcb¸kcqqwecÎÎfgq¸gqÎÎÎÎckm¸dgjcÎÎmpÎÎpmhcar¸rfpccÎÎÎÎ
```

Comment: Provide initial input?

Comment: hello

this is

an encrypted message

this is

a

demo file

for

project three

Comment: though I have it spread out over 8 lines

Comment: Well, then you got one of the preconditions wrong, because there are lower case, and upper case characters in here. As well as symbols. Your current code is only able to handle lower case characters. Additionally, the reason you're getting odd characters is because Python is used to handling UTF-8 and you probably only want ASCII conversion.

Comment: Ah, do you have any idea of how to change from UTF-8 to ASCII?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1762564/encoding-a-string-to-ascii